# How to not close the socket when closing the app on the phone in Android Studio

Tags: java, python, android, android-studio, sockets

I am building a client-server application that has a socket connection between them. the server is in Python, and is there a possibility that the connection will not close when I close the application
(in phone). Because it restricts me from notifications and more...
Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to keep a socket open when the app is not running.

Comment: as when you "close" the app but can continue listening to music, you need a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Answer (score 0):

you can't keep the tcp connection after the application closes you  should use push notification services such as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) when tcp connection is not available